# Blend/Interpolate between multiple Environment Textures based on Location

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, hdri

I am looking for a way to blend/interpolate between different environment textures based on location.  Similar to how realtime engines bake reflection map arrays and blend between them, but I will be capturing multiple HDRI panoramas from real world scenes.  This will be used for VFX-like projects.

Basically the idea that I have goes something like this:

- Capture multiple HDRI Panoramas from real-world scene location
- Recreate the location for each panorama in 3D scene (assign each HDRI to an empty object, perhaps?)
- Use nodes (if possible) to blend between different HDRI's based on proximity, ideally based on the individual ray bounce location rather than the object's origin.
- Possibly have a way to assign scale/weight to each HDRI
- Support for any number of HDRI panoramas

Is this feasible without heavy scripting, or by only utilizing Cycles nodes?  I know some of you will say this technique would be a bit too excessive, but there are some situations where this would be helpful.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Proximity to what? The camera?

Comment: Do you want to see the environment, or is it for lighting,,, something like [this](https://youtu.be/j6BNOfKCpAQ)?

Comment: @Leo Proximity to individual objects, or rather the location that each ray bounces off the object.

Comment: @RobinBetts Usually just for lighting and reflections, and with a composited background.  That technique could work in some cases.  My goal still is to get a method of interpolating between environmentalist textures.

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you mean by proximity... like... is it an objects position to another? From the center? Is the transformation in a single axis only, or would it be in all three?

Comment: @Leo Proximity from the initial ray bounce (from the camera) on a surface, to an empty object representing the location of an HDRI environment texture.

Comment: Dave

Bit late to the party here! Did you ever get an answer?

I believe it should be doable, haven't tried myself (but want to now!).
I saw a YT video by 'Çlassy Dog Films' where he mentioned using and blending between more than one HDRI as a CG car drives through a camera tracked scene.
He was using Blender for the CG car, and sounded like using more than one environment map was just something he did...

Comment: Of course I can't find the vid now! Shall have a try myself...